# Get the BALANCE for each item for every Row

Tags: sql, vba

I'm trying to perform a VBA Function or 1 solutions that minus row by row based on stock (available quantity), order by date. 
I'm actually using ADO to import item list & quantity, use SQL command to Group by STOCK Quantity from another sheet, and I planned to put all information to the same array, start to minus rows by row OR use SQL command do anything in recordset (just an idea, I don't know whether is it possible/ good way or not).
I hope to have any example that similarly to this or any keyword that I can find and learn. Also, any idea and comment will be greatly appreciated.

This is the stock:

```
Item  Quantity
A     10
B     9
C     1
D     5
```

The result will be look like this:

```
Item  Date    Quantity  Balance
A     25 Dec  4         6
B     24 Dec  4         -4 
A     27 Dec  5         1
B     23 Dec  9         0
A     29 Dec  3         -2
D     21 Dec  4         1
D     25 Dec  3         -2
C     22 Dec  2         -1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: It's not at all clear how the second table is generated from the first one.

Comment: Hi Gordon. I'm using all in excel file. I need to download data from a lot of SQL in my workplace. There is not specific environment such as oracle or something. However, I did import data from other excel file by SQL String.

Comment: Hi Tim, Sorry my english not too good enough to describe all in details. However, this is how it works. For example Item "A". There are 3 rows, each rows have a date (this is actually the date I planned to use it). Total of items A in stock is 10, minus first date is 25 Dec which is 4 item, then I have balance is 6, continue minus the quantity 5 on 27 Dec, I have 1 left. Go on 29 Dec, I do not enough enough qty, that is show -2.

Comment: After you get data from database to Excel are you allowed to do all processing in Excel? Will you be satisfied with a Excel sheet Result table?

Comment: Alvin, I provided both SQL and Excel way to get your Balance by each row.

Answer (score 1):

Both in SQL and in Excel you can solve this:

**Access:**

I used Access but the SQL is pretty much standard; here is the DB design:
[image]

ItemList:
[image]

ItemConsumption:
[image]

**TotalConsumption** is the projection of ItemConsumption table added of two new fields:

1. calculated Balance field `[OriginalAmount]-[Consumption] AS Balance`
2. OriginalAmount is a SubQuery that queries the ItemList table `(SELECT ItemList.Quantity FROM ItemList WHERE ItemList.Item=ItemConsumption.Item) AS OriginalAmount`
   [image]

SQL of this last table:

```
SELECT ItemConsumption.Item, ItemConsumption.DateOutofStock, ItemConsumption.Quantity, 
    DSum("[Quantity]","ItemConsumption","[Item]='" & [Item] & "' AND [DateOutofStock]<=#" & [DateOutofStock] & "#") AS Consumption, 
    (SELECT ItemList.Quantity FROM ItemList WHERE ItemList.Item=ItemConsumption.Item) AS OriginalAmount, 
[OriginalAmount]-[Consumption] AS Balance
        FROM ItemConsumption
        ORDER BY ItemConsumption.Item, ItemConsumption.DateOutofStock;
```

**EXCEL:**

First we need to order the Results Table by Item and Date, both in crescent order:
[image]

I coupled the G column formula to the equality of D column itens; if above item is different from current item, it should VLOOKUP over original Item Quantity; if is equal, Balance of previous date result has the True value of Quantity; this logic translate itself in Balance Formula at D5 cell:

```
=IF(D5=D4; G4-F5; VLOOKUP(D5;$A$2:$B$5;2;FALSE)-F5)
```

[image]

Sorry about images in Portuguese, but layout helps because is pretty similar.
Anyway, the above formula is translated to English; on figure SE = IF, PROCV = VLOOKUP, FALSO = FALSE...

P.S.: Some useful links to start are the excellent [Allen Browne's site](http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html), [AccessProgrammers.uk](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/running-balance-query.223699/) and [here in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49406634/create-a-column-to-calculate-the-portion-of-balance-for-every-shipment-according) and in a [brother SO](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/147555/calculate-balance-for-every-row-by-sequentially-subtracting-each-rows-amount-fr)

P.S. 2: I did not touch VBA to provide these solutions; although certainly it is possible through convoluted procedural code with arrays, or using OOP in a more clean way, I really don't think that is the right tool for this job.